# jests __mocks__ folder won't work with typescript

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I am using jest `27.0`

I am using this mock in many tests:

```
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-sfn', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@aws-sdk/client-sfn'),
    SendTaskSuccessCommand: jest.fn(),
    SendTaskFailureCommand: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```

Therefore I wanted to use a `__mocks__` folder.

I have the following project setup. In my root folder there are all dependencies installed including the `@aws-sdk/client-sfn.ts`.
In the subfolder there is also a `package.json` and my folder where I want to write the tests. So I created this file:

`root/__mocks__/@aws-sdk/client-sfn/client-sfn.ts` :

```
export const SendTaskSuccessCommand = jest.fn();
export const SendTaskFailureCommand = jest.fn();
```

However when I want to use this in my test like this:

```
 expect(SendTaskSuccessCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      taskToken: 'task_token',
      output: JSON.stringify(expectedOutput),
    });
```

and run the test, I always get:

```
Error: expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mock the send function as below, you could try to add SendTaskSuccessCommand as well.

`const mockResponse = jest.fn();
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-sfn', () => {
const originalModule = jest.requireActual('@aws-sdk/client-sfn');

```
class MockSFNClient {
  constructor() {}

  send() {
        return Reflect.apply(mockResponse, this, []);
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(MockSFNClient.prototype, originalModule.SFNClient.prototype);

return {
  ...originalModule,
  SFNClient: MockSFNClient
};
```

});`